# How to correct the code to get the graphs of ALL functions together in one graph?

Tags: matlab, function, math, sequence

This is related to an old question of mine. I was trying to plot the graphs of the functions `f_k(t)=t+k`   for    `1<=k<=10`   in the , but whenever I write the following code

`syms t;
k=1;`
 `while k<=6;
    f_k(t)=k+t;
    ezplot(f_k,[0,5]);
    k=k+1;
end;`

it runs perfectly and gives me the graph of   `f_6(t)=t+6`  only. I checked with replacing 6 by 10 and the same thing happens. I checked the code, and couldn't detect any logical error. I also tried 1)using `@(t)` and function command in the while loop and 2)also using for loop, but couldn't plot because there were other errors.

a)What exactly is wrong with my code? 
b)How can I fix this without minimal correction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `ezplots`, the current figure is overwritten. Call `hold on` so the figure is not overwritten and `hold off` after the code to allow overwriting again.

Further I would recommend to use a for loop instead of while.

```
syms t;
hold on;
for k=1:6
    f_k(t)=k+t;
    ezplot(f_k,[0,5]);
end
hold off
```

Comment: If you use a for loop you don't need k=k+1.